# How to get response from "unicode domain name" with curl in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, php-curl

I want to get the content of a site with an unicode name ([http://خبر.com](http://%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1.com)). I tried below codes.

```
$site = "https://خبر.com/";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $site,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And this snippet

```
$response = file_get_contents($site);
```

And also I tried to get the IP of site, but I couldn't.
I tried other Unicode domain names and problem persisted.
And English domain names load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your Unicode domain name to ASCII using [idn_to_ascii()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php)

Should work fine once parsed.